# Fastlane's download_dsyms doesn't wait for dSYM files to process

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, fastlane

I have the following lane which aims to download the dSYM files from App Store Connect, and then upload them to Firebase Crashlytics. (Because my app has Bitcode enabled.)

```
    lane :upload_symbols do
       
        version = get_version_number()

        download_dsyms(
            api_key: <my API key>,
            version: version, 
            build_number: <build number>,
            app_identifier: <app identifier>,
            wait_for_dsym_processing: true,
            wait_timeout: 300
        )

        upload_symbols_to_crashlytics(
            gsp_path: <path to .plist file in my project>
        )

        clean_build_artifacts() 
    end
```

If I understand correctly, setting the `wait_for_dsym_processing` flag to `true` should make my lane wait for the dSYM files to be ready to use and then download them.

When I run it on my CI (GitLab CI) or even locally, on my MacBook Pro, I see this in the logs:

[image]

It looks like Fastlane immediately skips to the next action and uploads the dSYM files, but these earlier generated by Xcode. If I run this lane for the second time, after the processing is completed on Apple's side and the files are available for this app version, the dSYMs are being downloaded correctly and looks like everything is okay then.

The Fastlane version I use is `2.205.2`.

Has anyone run into the same problem?

Comment: For me it appears when i upload version of the application that contains IOS + WatchOS with bitcode enabled